# Как максимально обезопасить ОС Linux?

Tags: linux, безопасность

Добрый день, есть группа серверов на Линукс(rpm based), решил уделить внимание на безопасность ОС, настроил согласно рекомендациям CIS, но для уверенности хотел спросить у вас, что еще предпринять чтобы максимально обезопасить ОС?

Comment: Вы получили сертификат "Center for Internet Security" ?

Comment: Нет, скачал цис бенчмарки

Comment: Мне кажется, что если Вы действительно "настроил согласно рекомендациям CIS", то этого хватит с избытком! Насколько я помню последнюю статистику, 95% случаев несанкционированного доступа происходят из-за "человеческого фактора", а вовсе не из-за дырок в системе защиты.

Comment: дело в том что я сейчас делаю продукт который бы автоматизировал бы рутинную задачу у администраторов (не касается тру админов) по этой причине хотел узнать, хватит ли выполнение рекомендаций от цис для повышения безопасности ос.

Comment: @Red_Hat подобных вопросов очень много в сети. Самый первый шаг, чему учат на курсах по сетевой безопасности в не завистмости от использоваемого решения - это составить политику доступа в компании, кто куда должен иметь доступ, обозначить группы и зоны.